# How to solve a ggscatter issue?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, ggpubr

A scatter plot using ggpubr package gives the error:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , x) : undefined columns selected.

Any suggestions.

```
ggscatter(myframe, x= "myframe$V1", y= "myframe$V2", add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE,cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson", xlab = "XXX", ylab = "YYY")

V1 V2
1 92 62.0
2 98 16.1
3 92 54.5
4 98 54.5
5 92 54.5
6 92 83.1
```

Comment: Just use `x=V1, y=V2`, you don't need the quotes or the name of the dataframe (as you have already specified it in the first argument)

Comment: Tried that before but I get : Error in .check_data(data, x, y, combine = combine | merge != "none") : 
  Can't find the y elements in the data.

Comment: How about `x="V1", y="V2"`, which seems to be the format suggested in one of the examples in the help for `ggscatter`?

Comment: When I use x="V1", y="V2": Error in data[, x] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Can you add the output of `dput(head(myframe))` to your question?

Comment: structure(list(V1 = c(92L, 98L, 92L, 98L, 92L, 92L), V2 = c(62, 
16.1, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 83.1)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Thanks. It works for me with `ggscatter(myframe, x= "V1", y= "V2", add = ...`

Comment: ggscatter(myframe, x = "V1", y = "V2" , add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE,cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson", xlab = "XXX", ylab = "YYY")
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type quosure/formula. Defaulting to continuous.
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type quosure/formula. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in validDetails.text(x) : 
  'pairlist' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: `myframe <- structure(list(V1 = c(92L,...` as above, then `ggscatter(myframe, x="V1", ...` as above, works fine for me, so I've no idea why yours should throw that error.

Comment: A more effective way to describe V1 = c(92L,..... #say we have 700 V1 readings in that column...